# How to connect to the postgres tables using python and find the ddl commands and triggers using python

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

- First go to the table name extract DDL command  to create table it would be like below

```
"""CREATE TABLE vendors (
            vendor_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            vendor_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        )"""
---
create trigger abc after
insert
    on
    public.abc_locks for each row execute function abc();
create trigger def before
update
    on
    public.def_locks for each row execute function def()
```

- For each table in the database there DDL commands has to add in one excel sheet with header column 'DDL query'
  *For each table in the database  if is there Trigger commands has to add in same excel sheet with header column 'Table Trigger' other wise column blank
- IF table trigger is present then go to Functions of table then extract source query of the trigger and put in the third column with 'Table Trigger details'. In the Function of the table the name will be same as the trigger name with parenthesis.

My Code is below

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

# Function to extract DDL command for a table
def extract_table_ddl(table_name, cursor):
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, is_nullable
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = %s
    """, (table_name,))

    columns = cursor.fetchall()

    if len(columns) == 0:
        return ""

    ddl_command = f"CREATE TABLE public.{table_name} (\n"
    for column in columns:
        column_name = column[0]
        data_type = column[1]
        character_maximum_length = column[2]
        is_nullable = column[3]

        column_definition = f"    {column_name} {data_type}"
        if character_maximum_length:
            column_definition += f"({character_maximum_length})"

        if not is_nullable:
            column_definition += " NOT NULL"

        ddl_command += f"{column_definition},\n"

    ddl_command = ddl_command.rstrip(",\n") + "\n);"

    return ddl_command


# Function to extract trigger information for a table
def extract_table_triggers(table_name, cursor):
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT trigger_name
        FROM information_schema.triggers
        WHERE event_object_table = %s
    """, (table_name,))
    triggers = cursor.fetchall()
    trigger_names = [trigger[0] for trigger in triggers]
    return trigger_names

# Function to extract trigger details (source query) for a trigger function
def extract_trigger_details(trigger_names, cursor):
    trigger_details = []
    for trigger_name in trigger_names:
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT pg_get_triggerdef(t.oid)
            FROM pg_trigger t
            WHERE t.tgname = %s
        """, (trigger_name,))
        trigger_query = cursor.fetchone()
        if trigger_query is not None:
            trigger_details.append(trigger_query[0])
    return '\n'.join(trigger_details)



# Database connection
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="mydb",
    user="postgres",
    password="postgres"
)

# Create a cursor object
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Get all table names in the database
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
""")

tables = cursor.fetchall()
table_names = [table[0] for table in tables]

# Initialize Excel data
data = {'Table Name': [], 'DDL Query': [], 'Table Trigger': [], 'Table Trigger Details': []}

# Extract DDL commands and trigger information for each table
for table_name in table_names:
    ddl_query = extract_table_ddl(table_name, cursor)
    trigger_names = extract_table_triggers(table_name, cursor)

    data['Table Name'].append(table_name)
    data['DDL Query'].append(ddl_query)

    if trigger_names:
        data['Table Trigger'].append(', '.join(trigger_names))
        trigger_details = []
        for trigger_name in trigger_names:
            trigger_function_name = f"{trigger_name}_fnc()"
            trigger_detail = extract_trigger_details(trigger_function_name, cursor)
            trigger_details.append(trigger_detail)
        data['Table Trigger Details'].append('\n'.join(trigger_details))
    else:
        data['Table Trigger'].append('')
        data['Table Trigger Details'].append('')

# Close the cursor and database connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()

# Convert data to DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Save DataFrame to Excel
df.to_excel('table_ddl_triggers.xlsx', index=False)
```

- My`Table Trigger Details` columns is empty. where ever `Table Trigger` is available corresponding rows also will have the `Trigger query`
- ps version: ('PostgreSQL 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-4.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit',)